# Retrieving Byte[0]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to save files into my Db with this code:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("CandidateCreate")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult CandidateCreatePost([Bind("Name,Number,Profile,CV,CVID")]Candidate candidate, IFormFile Corriculum)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //if (Corriculum != null)
                //{
                //    if (Corriculum.Length > 0)
                //    {
                        using (var applicationContext = new ApplicationContext())
                        {
                            byte[] p1 = null;
                            using (var fs1 = Corriculum.OpenReadStream())
                            using (var ms1 = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                fs1.CopyTo(ms1);
                                p1 = ms1.ToArray();

                            }
                            candidate.CV = p1;
                    //    }
                    //}
                }
                //candidate.CV = p1;
                candidateRepository.Add(candidate);
                candidateRepository.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Candidate");
            }
        }


        catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
        {
            //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                "Try again, and if the problem persists " +
                "see your system administrator.");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

I have changed my code to this, but Curriculum is always null? why is that?? 
I'm getting this error "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @mjwills Saving a file into my DB, where also in the same table will be other Candidate data, The file needs to be saved as a link or somethng like that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading Files into Database with ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106190/uploading-files-into-database-with-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: @mjwills that is asp.net mvc im using asp.net core ...

Comment: @mjwills already did and only found examples that saves the filies into a temp folder, and that isn't what I need as I said I need to store it into a DB

Comment: My bad then, sorry for all this confusion!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42741170/how-to-save-images-to-database-using-asp-net-core .

Comment: @mjwills I have edited my code, can you check it please ?

Comment: My guess is that your payload doesn't include a file input with the name of `Corriculum`.

Comment: You mean in my db?

Comment: No, in your HTML form.

Comment: @mjwills but I do, <input type="file" name="Corriculum" id="Corriculum">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I mannaged to make it work this way:

```
  [HttpPost, ActionName("CandidateCreate")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public  IActionResult CandidateCreatePost([Bind("Name,Number,Profile,CV,CVID")] Candidate candidate, IFormFile CV)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (CV != null)
            {
                if (CV.Length > 0)
                {
                    byte[] p1 = null;
                    using (var fs1 = CV.OpenReadStream())
                    using (var ms1 = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        fs1.CopyTo(ms1);
                        p1 = ms1.ToArray();

                    }
                    candidate.CVNAME = CV.FileName;
                    candidate.CV = p1;
                    }
                }
            using (var applicationContext = new ApplicationContext())
            {
                candidateRepository.Add(candidate);
                 candidateRepository.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Candidate");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```