# Save all kinds of files with ASP.NET Core application in database

Tags: asp.net-core, file-sharing

I am working on a project where I have to save all kinds of files in a database (PDF, images, video's, ...). Is this possible with a normal database? At this time the files are stored on one project in the static files but because I have two projects I would like a more central storage.

Comment: what do you mean about safe? Do you want to save a file in database?

Comment: Execuse me for the typo, I want to SAVE them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save Images to database using ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42741170/how-to-save-images-to-database-using-asp-net-core)

Comment: You can save any file into SQL Server tables in varbinary DataType or you can use FileTable.

Comment: So this will also work for PDF's and video's?

Comment: You can save any file to the database with this code, but beware of FileSize and security issue of malicious files!

Comment: Okay, will take that into account! Thanks!