# What is the alternative of Httpcontext.Current.Request.Files in Asp.Net Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243068/access-httpcontext-current), which suggests that I can use `IHttpContextAccessor` to access `HttpContext.Current`. But I want to specifically receive files which that object doesn't seem to have.

So is there any alternative for `Httpcontext.Current.Request.Files` in Asp.Net Core 2.0

Comment: Are you trying to upload a file?

Comment: @Kirk Sorry yes, I have updated the question. It is `IHttpContextAccessor`. But its object does not have `HttpContext.Current` or `Request.Files` property. It is deprecated in Core I think. And I am not finding its alternative.

Comment: @Rob Yes. I am trying to find uploaded file.

Comment: Related post - [MVC 6 HttpPostedFileBase?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29836342/465053)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Inside controller context and in action you can access files via `HttpContext.Request.Form.Files`:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;

    return View();
}
```

and outside controller you have to inject `IHttpContextAccessor`.

for upload file read [File uploads in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads).

Comment: Woah..They migrated it to `Form`. I didn't notice it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Uploading file in Asp.Net Core 2.0 is done with an interface IFormFile that you would take as a parameter in your post action.

Lets say you have an ajax post that will call the POST action and upload a file.
You would first create the form data.

```
var data = new FormData();

data.set("file", $("#uploadControl").val())

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "upload",
   data: data,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false
});
```

Your action would look like this

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Upload(IFormFile file)
{
   //save the file
}
```

Please do not copy/paste this as this is just the general idea of how to do it.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this method and revert you