# 'HttpPostedFileBase' in Asp.Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm recently working on a ReactJS app that's calling an API (developed with .NET Core 2.0).

My question is how to use `HttpPostedFileBase`  in an .NET Core 2.0 API in order to get file content and save it in database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC 6 HttpPostedFileBase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836342/mvc-6-httppostedfilebase)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You don't have `HttpPostedFileBase` in ASP.NET Core 2.0, but you can use `IFormFile`.

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

    // full path to file in temp location
    var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

    foreach (var formFile in files)
    {
        if (formFile.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }
    }

    // process uploaded files
    // Don't rely on or trust the FileName property without validation.

    return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePath});
}
```

More here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1

`IFormFile` is in the following namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http`.

Answer (score 20):

`HttpPostedFileBase` doesn't exist in ASP.NET Core. You should use `IFormFile` now, instead. However, that only works when you send the request as `multipart/form-data`, which you're likely not doing if you're working with a client-side framework like React. If you're posting JSON, you should set the JSON member that corresponds with your file property with the file encoded as a Base64 string. Server-side, you should then bind to `byte[]`.

Answer (score 11):

If anyone finds this by searching for `HttpPostedFileBase` it's possible you're familiar with writing ASP.NET controller methods something like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DoThing(MyViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase fileOne, HttpPostedFileBase fileTwo)
{
   //process files here
}
```

If you're wanting to write an equivalent in ASP.NET Core then you can write it like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DoThing(MyViewModel model, IFormFile fileOne, IFormFile fileTwo)
{
   //process files here
}
```

i.e. the only change needed to the method signature is replacing `HttpPostedFileBase` with `IFormFile`. You will then need to modify your method to work with the new parameter type (e.g. `HttpPostedFileBase` has an `InputStream` property, whereas `IFormFile` has a `OpenReadStream()` method) but I think the details of those differences are beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 7):

You should also be able to get the files like this :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFiles()
    {
        var files = Request.Form.Files;
        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using YourNamespace.Models;

namespace YourNamespace.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private static List<FileModel> uploadedFiles = new List<FileModel>();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadFile()
        {
            var model = new FileModel
            {
                Id = uploadedFiles.Count + 1,
                Name = Request.Form["Name"],
                PdfFile = Request.Files["PdfFile"]
            };

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                model.UploadFile();
                uploadedFiles.Add(model);
            }

            return View("Index", uploadedFiles);
        }

        public ActionResult ViewPdf(int id)
        {
            var fileModel = uploadedFiles.Find(f => f.Id == id);
            if (fileModel != null)
            {
                // Specify the directory where you want to retrieve the files
                string uploadDir = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/storeFile");
                string fileName = $"{fileModel.Id}_{fileModel.Name}.pdf";
                string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadDir, fileName);

                return File(filePath, "application/pdf", fileName);
            }

            return HttpNotFound();
        }
    }
}
```

```css
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

namespace YourNamespace.Models
{
    public class FileModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase PdfFile { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public void UploadFile()
        {
            if (PdfFile != null && PdfFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Specify the directory where you want to store the files
                    string uploadDir = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/storeFile");
                    if (!Directory.Exists(uploadDir))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadDir);
                    }

                    // Save the file to the specified directory
                    string fileName = $"{Id}_{Name}.pdf";
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadDir, fileName);
                    PdfFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                    Message = "File uploaded successfully.";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Message = "Error uploading file: " + ex.Message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Message = "Please select a file.";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>File Upload</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Uploaded Files</h2>

    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <script>
            var uploadedFiles = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
            for (var i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.length; i++) {
                document.write('<tr>');
                document.write('<td>' + uploadedFiles[i].Id + '</td>');
                document.write('<td>' + uploadedFiles[i].Name + '</td>');
                document.write('<td><a href="/Home/ViewPdf?id=' + uploadedFiles[i].Id + '" target="_blank">View PDF</a></td>');
                document.write('</tr>');
            }
        </script>
    </table>

    <h2>Upload File</h2>

    <form action="/Home/UploadFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="Name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" required />
        <br />
        <input type="file" name="PdfFile" id="PdfFile" required />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!