# ASP.NET Core MVC post receiver error 415 if specify [FromBody]

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am developing a controller in ASP.NET Core 6.0 and I want to implement a post consumer that accept binary images.

If I write the signature in this way:

```cs
[HttpPost("image/{pv}/{articolo}"), 
 Consumes("image/jpeg", new string[] { "image/jpg", "image/png", "image/tiff", "image/tif" }),
 SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status200OK), 
 SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, "nel caso in cui PV o articolo non esistono")]
public async Task<IActionResult> postImage(string pv, string articolo, [FromBody] Stream fileStream)
{ 
    /* use fileStream to save into disk*/ 
}
```

The swagger works great:
[image: screenshot of swagger]
But If I try it returns error 415 "Unsupported Media Type"

I tried removing [FromBody], the only way to not get 415 is remove the parameter and use Request.Body, but I need the swagger as documentation.

Comment: I don't think `Stream` is the correct type to use here, try `[FromBody] IFormFile formFile` instead.

Comment: There's a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51021182/httppostedfilebase-in-asp-net-core-2-0 which was asking about the ASP.NET Core equivalent to `HttpPostedFileBase` that was the correct type for .NET Framework.

Comment: `IFormFile` it is for file inside a form, it is not my case.

Comment: I already have a webservice that takes Images using post with `content-type: image/jpeg` it is not possible do it in .net core?