# Get file from Request over .NET Core Api

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-core, restsharp

I don't know, how I can get the file over my .NET Core API and save it as a file.

For example:
I upload my test file with the following method:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        var client = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://localhost:44356/api/");

        var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("Upload", RestSharp.Method.POST);
        request.AddFile(
            "test",
            "c:\\kill\\test.wav");

        client.Execute(request);
    }
```

And my API receives a request.
This method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UploadFile() {
        using(var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body)) {
            var body = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

My body variable contains this:

> -------------------------------28947758029299
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test"; filename="test.wav"
>   Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>   RIFF^b

And now my question:

How can I get the file and save it on my disc?

I use .NET Core 2.1 Webapi & on my Client Restsharp version 106.3.1.

Comment: Related post - [MVC 6 HttpPostedFileBase?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29836342/465053)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to determine how you want to send the file, i.e. the encoding type. That determines how the request body is interpreted. If you want to use `multipart/form-data`, then your action signature needs to look like:

```
public IActionResult UploadFile(IFormFile test) { // since you made the key "test"
```

Then, you can get the actual file data via either:

```
byte[] bytes;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    await test.CopyToAsync(ms);
    bytes = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Or, if you want to utilize the stream directly:

```
using (var stream = test.OpenReadStream())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh wow. I named the variable of IFormFile simply "file", not "test". Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. The param name doesn't *always* matter, but if you're posting something directly to a param, then the name does matter.