# dropzone and asp.net core 3.1 - whats the proper param to be sent to controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dropzone.js

i have this in my razor view:

```
<div id="dropzone">
<form action="/Controller/Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
      id="my-awesome-dropzone" class="dropzone needsclick dz-clickable dropzone-previews">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div ></div>
    <div class="dz-message needsclick">
        <button type="button" class="dz-button">Drop files here or click to upload.</button><br />
    </div>
    <span class="note needsclick">

    </span>
</form>
```

and this in my js:

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
  maxFiles: mediaMax,
  maxFilesize: maxSize,
  uploadMultiple: true,
  accept: function (file, done) {
    if (file.name === "justinbieber.jpg") {
        done("Naha, you don't.");
    }
    else { done(); }
},
  init: function () {
    this.on("sending", function (file, response, formData) {
        formData["__RequestAntiForgeryToken"] = document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[1].value;
    });
    this.on("sendingmultiple", function (file, response, formData) {
        formData["__RequestAntiForgeryToken"] = document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[1].value;
    });
    this.on("success", function (file, response) {
        file.serverID = response.id;
    });
    this.on("error", function (file, response) {
        var r = response;
        console.log("Drop Err:");
        console.log(r);
    });
}};
```

in my controller i have tried this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [FormAttributes.DisableFormValueModelBinding]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
```

and this

```
        [HttpPost]
    [FormAttributes.DisableFormValueModelBinding]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
```

both file and files return 0 or null

the only that works is

```
    [HttpPost]
    [FormAttributes.DisableFormValueModelBinding]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var more = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
            ... do stuff
        } }
```

where i basically ignore the input param of files
can anyone tell me what the proper parameters for Upload is?

for ref i looked at the following links:
[MVC 6 HttpPostedFileBase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836342/mvc-6-httppostedfilebase)
https://dotnetthoughts.net/uploading-images-aspnet-core-and-dropzone/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the option `uploadMultiple` set to `true`, then Dropzone will append `[]` to the paramName. After looking at the request from a html5 multiple file upload I noticed the request does not add the indexes to the filename (files[n]). Dropzone.js does this so there is a work around. If you add the paramName option to Dropzone JS config and have it call a method which returns files you will get the same behaviour as the html5 multiple file upload. You could also refer to [this link](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration-options) for more details on Configuration options of Dropzone.js

*Razor view and js*

```
<div id="dropzone">
  <form action="/Home/Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
      id="myAwesomeDropzone" class="dropzone needsclick dz-clickable dropzone-previews">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div></div>
    <div class="dz-message needsclick">
        <button type="button" class="dz-button">Drop files here or click to upload.</button><br />
    </div>
    <span class="note needsclick">

    </span>
</form>
```

```
@section Scripts
 {
  <link rel="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/dropzone.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/dropzone.js"></script>
  <script>
   function myParamName() {
       return "files";
    }

    Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    paramName: myParamName, // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    maxFiles: 5,
    maxFilesize: 100,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    accept: function (file, done) {
        if (file.name === "justinbieber.jpg") {
            done("Naha, you don't.");
        }
        else { done(); }
    },
    init: function () {
        this.on("sending", function (file, response, formData) {
            formData["__RequestAntiForgeryToken"] = document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken").value;
        });
        this.on("sendingmultiple", function (file, response, formData) {
            formData["__RequestAntiForgeryToken"] = document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken").value;
        });
        this.on("success", function (file, response) {
            file.serverID = response.id;
        });
        this.on("error", function (file, response) {
            var r = response;
            console.log("Drop Err:");
            console.log(r);
        });
    }};
  </script>
}
```

*Controller*

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
```

*Result*
[image]

Comment: hey @xueli thx for the answer - so are you saying this is a bug in dropzone? "After looking at the request from a html5 multiple file upload I noticed the request does not add the indexes to the filename (files[n])" and we have to do a workaround

Comment: @toy, yes. If you find my workaround works, could you mark my reply as the answer ? This will help others who faces the same or similar issue to find the answer quickly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: unfortunately my question was SPECIFICALLY what is NOT the workaround

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR summary of @Xueli Chen's answer:

Frontend:

```
function workaroundDropzone() {
 return "files";
}

new Dropzone("div#yourId", { 
    paramName: workaroundDropzone,
    uploadMultiple: true
});
```

Backend:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> DropzoneActionHandler(ICollection<IFormFile> files) {

}
```

Trick is in creating a method returning string with desired param name, Dropzone won't override it with `[]` as it would if `paramName` would be set to a string. Tested with version 5.2.7