# Request.Files in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net, ajax, file, upload, asp.net-core

I am trying to upload files using aspnet core using ajax request . 
In previous versions of .net i used to handle this using

```
 foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
                //Save file content goes here

                fName = file.FileName;
     (...)
```

but now its showing error at request.files how can i get it to work ? i searched and found that httppostedfile has been changed to iformfile but how to handle request.files?

Comment: take a look at these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443305/how-can-i-upload-a-file-in-mvc-6-under-vnext  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836342/mvc-6-httppostedfilebase especially this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27980038/5426333

Comment: thanks for comment , i actually found that `IFormFile file in Request.Form.Files` now i am stucked at getting the parameter values

Comment: `Request.Form.Files[fileName]` ?

Answer (score 63):

This is working code from a recent project. Data has been moved from **Request.Files** to **Request.Form.Files**.
In case you need to convert stream to byte array - this is the only implementation that worked for me. Others would return empty array.

```
using System.IO;
var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
foreach (var formFile in Request.Form.Files)
{
   if (formFile.Length > 0)
   {
      using (var inputStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
      {
         // read file to stream
         await formFile.CopyToAsync(inputStream);
         // stream to byte array
         byte[] array = new byte[inputStream.Length];
         inputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
         inputStream.Read(array, 0, array.Length);
         // get file name
         string fName = formFile.FileName;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This code works for 100% for both files uploaded using regular form or ajax:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IList<IFormFile> files)
{
  foreach (IFormFile source in files)
  {
    string filename = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(source.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

    filename = this.EnsureCorrectFilename(filename);

    using (FileStream output = System.IO.File.Create(this.GetPathAndFilename(filename)))
      await source.CopyToAsync(output);
  }

  return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
}

private string EnsureCorrectFilename(string filename)
{
  if (filename.Contains("\\"))
    filename = filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

  return filename;
}

private string GetPathAndFilename(string filename)
{
  return this.HostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\files\\" + filename;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What about this merge from two good solutions I came around :

```
var myBytes  = await GetByteArrayFromImageAsync(Request.Form.Files[0]); 

private async Task<byte[]> GetByteArrayFromImageAsync(IFormFile file)
{
  using (var target = new MemoryStream())
  {
    await file.CopyToAsync(target);
    return target.ToArray();
  }
}
```