# Request.Files["XXX"].SaveAs() equivalent in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

```
public ActionResult SaveFile()
    {
        var uniqueName = "";
        var file = Request.Form.Files["myfile"];
        if (Request.Form.Files["myfile"] != null)
        {
            if (file.FileName != "")
            {
                var ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                uniqueName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ext;
                string fileSavePath = Path.Combine(V, uniqueName);
                file.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
            }
        }
        //...
        return Json(data, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings());
    }
```

Initially the line of code `var file = Request.Form.Files["myfile"];` was written as `var file = Request.Files["myfile"];` in the ASP.Net MVC. After I converted it to Form.Files[] for the ASP.Net Core MVC, reference of the `.SaveAs` got missed up.

Can you help how can we achieve this?
Do we need to change the line `var file = Request.Form.Files["myfile"];` or Is there any other built-in function for the `.SaveAs` other than this?

Comment: [Does this answer useful to you ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44174182/7687666)

Comment: I tried this, it didnt work

Comment: [Dmitry Sikorsky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37689530/7687666) in the end of the post I provided to you, should be the correct way to get file and save file in .net core.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `it didnt work`, how do you use it?